# Delete image in database

Tags: php, database, image

I'm trying to delete specific images in a database through PHP.

I have a page where all images in the database are displayed and I wanted a button under each one of them so I could delete them individually through their id but I don't know how.

Here's the PHP code for showing all images:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM galeria");
?>
<h5>Images:</h5>
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?><h6> <?php echo $row['titleimg']; ?></h6>
    <p><?php echo $row['events_id']; ?></p>
    <img src="../images/<?php echo $row["img"]; ?>" width="301px" height="200px"/>
    <form action="delete_images.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
    </form>
    <?php
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

So now, what's the code I should have in my "delete_images.php" file?

Comment: Well, what do you think? First of all a question: Once you are on _delete\_images.php_ - do you know which picture should be deleted?

Comment: Did you stored each an image in a single row on the table?

Comment: That's the thing kingkero. I wanted it to delete the right image by using the id of the image that the user chose to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form needs an additional piece of information, an identifier for the image to be deleted.  Something like:

```
<form action="delete_images.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['img_id'] ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Naturally, I'm guessing on the column name (`img_id`), but any identifier for that specific image will do the trick.  With that, your POST to `delete_images.php` will have that value (in `$_POST['id']`) and can use it in the DELETE query to the database.

Comment: I've already tried something really close to that and it didn't work but now it did so thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Put a hidden input  field that will contain the imageName to which you want to delete.

```
<input type="hidden" value="'.$row["img"].'" name="imageName" />

// Now write some server side code in delete_images.php that will delete file 

  if (array_key_exists('imageName', $_POST)) {
  $filename = $_POST['imageName'];
  if (file_exists($filename)) {
   unlink($filename);
  // Write Mysql query that will delete the row from database
  echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
   } else {
    echo 'Could not delete '.$filename.', file does not exist';
   }
   }
```